# Which one is the cheapest to use AWS RDS or my own database?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have wordpress application running on my EC2 - AWS. I haven't decide which one is Amazon RDS or my own database on different hosting. Which one is the cheapest to use? Let's say I have my own MySQL database from Lunarpages or Bluehost hosting, to allow my wordpress on EC2 instance to connect/remote to my database on Lunarpages not allow my wordpress to connect remote to Amazon RDS. Which one is the cheapest to use? I heard people saying when you use Amazon RDS is very expensive, so I thought maybe to save costs to allow my wordpress to connect to my own database not Amazon RDS for wordpress. I don't know it is true or not. I don't know how it performance well. Which one is the best one. Any suggestion appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to use RDS when running MySQL on AWS. You can easily run MySQL on native EC2 - you'll have to manage the DB yourself, but it will be cheaper than RDS. And, as others have mentioned, you should generally locate the DB close to the apps using it so running both WordPress and MySQL in the same AWS AZ would be preferable.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for the info. I am new to EC2 and AWS. What if one of those EC2 instance went down and database on native EC2 went down together and will it wipe all the data out?

Comment: As with any database deployment, you should have procedures in place to backup and restore data. You can pay to have AWS manage this, and more, for you using RDS or you can manage it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running on a different hosting will cause extra latency.

Let's do the math on AWS RDS for the smallest instances (taking eu-west-1 region as example)

1. Running on RDS: db.t2.micro $0.018 per hour, or $12.96 per month for RDS. Free the first year under [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/).
2. Running on EC2: t2.micro (You configure MySQL and backups, ...), $0.0126 per hour, or $9.07 per month. Free the first year under [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

If your application is small enough, you could host both your database and your application on the same machine (solution 2)

Comment: My plan is to use 1. wordpress on www.example.com for simple marketing to show my iOS app products. 2. api.example.com for my iOS applications to connect to API (lots of requests data). Do you think it is enough both of my options to your (solution 2)?

Comment: It all depends on the amount of visitors. It will be enough for a normal average site

Comment: You could also consider using Amazon Lightsail. There is a [Wordpress configuration available for $5/month](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/) and there's a free tier for that too, I think.

Comment: 20$ for an "average site" sounds way too expensive

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree with that. In amazon AWS, the first thing you do is set up a virtual private network and create the corresponding network access interfaces.  My experience working with heavy CMSs is that the architecture is much more stable with EC2 + RDS, each in one instance. In addition RDS has automated version maintenance and it is much more difficult to fail or suffer a crash, as opposed to a mysql or similar, running on the same virtual machine.

Also in terms of speed and performance, working with this scheme for example in wordpress, the system flies, the speed is much higher and appreciable even with small machines.

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise is not good to have database on a totally different network of the website hosted itself. It'll delay. Imagine if you have a lot of calls, it'll multiply the delay.

You can host a local database on the EC2 it'self, this would be the best choice.

Comment: Delays can not multiply, only sum up. But your point is valid. +1

Comment: Security wise it is always better to have a database on a different subnet.